# Mobile vision api barcode is not working on samsung tablet SM-T311?

Tags: android

I looked into mobile vision API barcode scanner and successfully integrated. But I found that it's not working on my Samsung tablet. Though I debugged and checked as per the documentation it needs some native libraries to be downloaded when the app is installed for the first time. But when I debugged it showed up barcodeDetector.isOperational(), means It can operate. But I when I place on barcode its doing nothing.

> Do mobile vision api works on poor quality camera such as 5MP.?  and does it depends on autoFocus feature of device. does os version of a device matters? Current OS of my device is 4.4.2 and Latest Google Play service of 11.5.09.

Can anyone help me out?